# ssed Unterminated s command

Tags: regex, macos, sed, terminal

I'm trying to do a search and replace with ssed on the following. However, it keeps giving me an `unterminated s command` error. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Using zsh on OSX.

```
> ssed -r 's/(?s).*?(<div class="mb_t_p_t_post_div">.*);\1;/g' 1.htm
ssed: -e expression #1, char 50: unterminated `s' command
```

Comment: count the number of '/' chars in your cmd. there should be 3. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a `/` between the search and replace patterns. Should be:

```
sed -r 's/(?s).*?(<div class="mb_t_p_t_post_div">.*);/\1;/g' 1.htm
```

There's also a problem with `(?s)` - it's not valid.

Comment: Thanks, completely missed that. Since `(?s)` is not valid, how would you include everything from the beginning of the file to the first instance of the expression? `[.\s]*?` only gives me the newline character just before it. Trying this out in Sublime.